# I am having autogenerated textbox. i want to addition the autogenerated textbox values

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have added multiple text box values using java script.. like multiple price.. i want to calculate total price
 this is my script fo autogenerate textbox
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {


enter code here
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

i have html code as

```
    <th>Description</th>           
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2">
        <th width="300">
            <input type="text" name="desc" size="43" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="text" name="code" />
        </th>
        <th>
           <input type="text"  name="qty" size="10"  class="txt"/>
        </th>

    </tr>
</table>
                               Total Qty:<span id="sum">0</span><input type="hidden" name="totalqty" align="right" id="sum" size="10" >
<button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add few more Rows!</button>
```

i have code for addition script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the each function takes two arguments

```
$(".txt").each(function(index, htmlElement){
    $(htmlElement).keyup(function(event){
        //do your code here
        calculateSum();
    })
});
```

your calculateSum will be like this

```
function calculateSum(){
    $(".txt").each(function(index, htmlElement){
        sum += parseFloat($(htmlElement).val());
    });
}
```

the first argument of callback function in each function is index number of the element in the array of selected elements

and second argument is the current selected element in the array of selected elements(html input elements).